# Definition of a Subharmonic Function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am reading a proof in a paper and it basically says:

> $u$ is subharmonic so we can assume for all $x\in \Omega$: $$u(x) = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{|B_R(x)|}\int_{B_R(x)}u$$

Shouldn't the $=$ sign be an $\leq$? I thought this was a typo, but I've found it now in two different places. For context, I've included part of the proof below.

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question. When it says 'we can assume that...' the question is: for what purpose? For proving a specific result it may be possible to reduce the proof to the case when equality holds. So more context is required

Answer (score 2):

Notice that there is a limit in front of the integral! I am happy to add more details if needed.

So $u$ is called subharmonic if $\Delta u \geq 0$. From this follows (or it can be shown) that for any point $a$ of the domain of $u$ and any positive radius $R$ one has
$$
u(a) \leq \frac{1}{B_R(a)} \int_{B_R(a)} u \,dx
$$
as well that for $R_1 < R_2$ 
$$
\frac{1}{B_{R_1}(a)} \int_{B_{R_1}(a)} u \,dx \leq \frac{1}{B_{R_2}(a)} \int_{B_{R_2}(a)} u \,dx
$$
holds. So one can take the limit to obtain
$$
u(a) = \lim_{R\searrow 0}\frac{1}{B_R(a)} \int_{B_R(a)} u \,dx.
$$

This is true since we have (for continuous $u$ at $a$)

$$
\left| u(a) - \frac{1}{B_r(a)}\int_{B_r(a)} u dx \right|
\leq
\frac{1}{B_r(a)}\int_{B_r(a)} |u(a) - u| dx
\leq \sup_{x\in B_R(a)} |u(a) - u(x)|
$$
and that will go to $0$ as $R$ goes to zero (from above).

Now, if you actually asking about the generalized version of a subharmonic function one can obtain a similar result at least almost everywhere.

Comment: Doesn't this just show: $$
u(a) \geq \lim_{R\searrow 0}\frac{1}{B_R(a)} \int_{B_R(a)} u \,dx.
$$ how is the other direction obtained?

Comment: (Sorry, notice that I mixed up the inequality before.)  What I was going for here, is that one can actually compute this limit. I will make it more explicit.

Comment: why can we assume $u$ is continuous?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you provide a definition of a subharmonic function $u$ first and then we can take it from there.

Comment: okay, so $u$ is subharmonic if for all $\phi \in C^{\infty}_0$ we have: $$0 \leq \int_\Omega - \phi  \Delta u$$ where $\Omega$ is a, potentially, unbounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I see, now this definition I am not aware of at all. Could you explain a bit? For example what does $u$ need to fulfill? Is $\Delta u$ meant in a weak sense? Or is $u$ actually $C^2$?